# What happens if I try to revert a commit that has already been reverted?

Tags: git, github, version-control, versioning

I'm trying to understand what happens in the following `git-revert` scenario.

By running

```
git revert abcdef
```

I sucessfully reverted the commit (step 1). Then (step 2), I made some changes and created a new commit by running

```
touch a.txt && git commit -a -m 'test commit
```

Now (step 3) I'm trying to revert the commit again which was already reverted in Step 1.

```
git revert abcdef
```

What will happen in step 3?

Comment: Note that `touch a.txt && git commit -a -m 'test commit` won't create a commit; you'd need to stage `a.txt` after creating it (under the assumption that it doesn't already exist) for that.

Comment: Your command sequence should be like, touch a.txt && git add -u && git commit -a -m 'test commit.

Comment: It will clear your third step doubt, git revert just creates a new commit -- you can "remove" it with git reset --hard HEAD^ (be more careful with it, though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git-revert` man page describes the command thus:

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them.

When in doubt as to what a given command does, you can always conduct some experiment in a toy repository, to fix ideas. In the following (admittedly simple) example, reverting an already reverted commit is a no-op; no new commit gets created.

```sh
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init

$ touch README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "add README"

$ git revert master
# save commit message

$ touch a.txt
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -m "add a.txt"

$ git log --oneline
c1e798b add a.txt
a94219e Revert "add README"
27aba0d add README

$ git revert master~2
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git log --oneline
c1e798b add a.txt
a94219e Revert "add README"
27aba0d add README
```

---

#### Addendum (based on the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047067/what-happens-if-we-try-to-revert-a-commit-which-is-already-reverted-in-git/26048301?noredirect=1#comment40813288_26048301))

> One more question. Is it possible for a `git revert` to cause a merge conflict?

Yes. At the bottom of it, `git-revert` consists in applying a patch, and such an operation can give rise to conflicts. The toy example below produces one:

```sh
$ cd ~/Desktop && mkdir fruit && cd fruit
$ git init

# write one line and make a commit
$ printf "apples\n" > fruit.txt
$ git add fruit.txt
$ git commit -m "add fruit.txt"

# write a second line and make a commit
$ printf "oranges\n" >> fruit.txt 
$ git commit -am "add oranges to the list"

# in effect, replace the second line and make a commit
$ printf "apples\nbananas\n" > fruit.txt
$ git commit -am "replace oranges by bananas"

# inspect the log
$ git log --oneline
16e76af replace oranges by bananas
7736641 add oranges to the list
5c0257b add fruit.txt

# attempt to revert the commit that introduced the second line ("oranges")
$ git revert 7736641
error: could not revert 7736641... add oranges to the list
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Comment: More specifically, "revert" means "look at what this commit changed, and make a change that is the exact opposite".  In this particular case, the commit added `README`, so the opposite is to remove `README`.  Here you're asking git to remove `README` again, but it's already gone, so nothing happens.  If you revert the revert itself, the revert *removes* `README`, so reverting the revert re-*adds* `README`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
One more question.Is it possible for a `git revert` to cause a merge conflict?